# Condition in Two Date field with Two Date Parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

I have an ID field two date fields in table named as From_Date and To_Date. I want to select this dates with date criteria.

```
ID From_Date   To_Date
1  2011-05-03  2011-05-28
2  2011-04-29  2011-05-10
3  2011-05-09  2011-05-20
4  2011-04-28  2011-05-09
5  2011-04-29  2011-05-19
6  2011-05-09  2011-05-09
7  2011-05-09  2011-05-09
8  2011-05-09  2011-05-09
9  2011-05-21  2011-05-21
10 2011-06-06  2011-06-06
11 2011-05-21  2011-05-28
12 2011-05-14  2011-05-28
13 2011-05-23  2011-05-24
14 2011-05-27  2011-05-27
15 2011-05-23  2011-05-24
```

Now I want two parameter for condition of start date and end date
like

```
@StartDate = '05/01/2011'
@EndDate = '05/10/2011'
```

And I want Output from these parameters when ever array of dates between startdate and enddate parameter should be compare to array of dates between From_Date and To_Date field

Output:

```
ID From_Date   To_Date
1  2011-05-03  2011-05-18
2  2011-04-29  2011-05-10
3  2011-05-09  2011-05-20
4  2011-04-28  2011-05-09
5  2011-04-29  2011-05-19
6  2011-05-09  2011-05-09
7  2011-05-09  2011-05-09
8  2011-05-09  2011-05-09
```

is this possible in single query instead use of trigger or function?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow @Vinay Mistry, please do use of `{}`(tool bar button) for representing your code parts, data table values etc.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get all records which have `From_Date` or `To_Date` are in between your date range `(@StartDate and @EndDate)` then it's simple query like :

```
SELECT * FROM TableName
WHERE (From_Date BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate) OR (To_Date BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate);
```

Comment: Your suggestion doesn't take into account cases where `From_Date` is before `@StartDate` and `To_Date` is after `@EndDate`. According to the example output, that should be accounted too (see the row with `ID=5`).

Comment: @AndriyM : True, I have mentioned that in my answer. So for case ID=5, Mikael's answer is correct.

Answer (score 1):

```
select *
from YourTable
where From_Date <= @EndDate and
      To_Date >= @StartDate
```

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/113761/